# Can't run the elasticsearch image on Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, go

I get an error when trying to run the elasticsearch image on my raspberry pi. It runs fine on my mac, so it is probably operating system specific. I can run other images.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/folder/folder$ docker run 
node:latest
pi@raspberrypi:~/folder/folder$ docker run 
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.3
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "exec format 
error"
```

Having searched extensively for `standard_init_linux.go:195` it has yielded very little, apart from maybe having something to do with the `qemu` libray, from [this discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23865), but don't know enough about linux OS to really understand that.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/folder/folder$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.10.0-ce
 API version:  1.33
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   f4ffd25
 Built:        Tue Oct 17 19:13:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm

Server:
 Version:      17.10.0-ce
 API version:  1.33 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   f4ffd25
 Built:        Tue Oct 17 19:06:18 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
 Experimental: false
pi@raspberrypi:~/folder/folder$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Could it be to do with the Go version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker image is for i386 architectures. The raspberry pi is arm and it's not supported.

Probably you'll find something from hypriot images or you can try to use charlesyan/rpi-elasticsearch image.

Comment: I see... so how can I run the same docker-compose on my mac as on my pi? do I need two different routes dependent upon architecture?

Comment: IIRC the docker team is planning to develop a better multi arch support for the images in the future versions of docker. For the moment unfortunately I don't have an easy solution.